# How can I remove a class from an element with jQuery based on some characters of the class name?

Tags: jquery

I have elements with classes that can be like this:

```
class="refType indent_00"
class="refType indent_01"
class="refType indent_02"
..
class="refType indent_10"
```

Is there an easy way that I can remove the index_xx class from these?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all the objects you might find the `index_xx` class name on also have the `refType` class on them, then you can do this:

```
$(".refType").each(function() {
    this.className = $.trim(this.className.replace(/(^|\s)indent_\d+($|\s)/, " "));
});
```

If, they don't all have  the `refType` class, then you can do this:

```
$("[class*='indent_']").each(function() {
    this.className = $.trim(this.className.replace(/(^|\s)indent_\d+($|\s)/, " "));
});​
```

Or, using all jQuery, you can do this:

```
$("[class*='indent_']").removeClass(function(i, cls) {
    var retVal = "";
    var matches = cls.match(/(^|\s)(indent_\d+)($|\s)/);
    if (matches) {
        retVal = matches[2];
    }
    return(retVal);
});
```

The first one is probably more efficient.  If you can scope this to some part of the DOM rather than the entire DOM, then that may help performance.

Working example of the second one here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PkXag/

Answer (score 1):

Use [jquery removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/); e.g.:

```
$('.refType').removeClass('indent_00');
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/PT8WB/).

Comment: I think the question is asking how to remove all `indent_xx` classes regardless of number.