# Modifying a class name through reference to the parent with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I had some help and some suggestions on how to remove a class name.

[Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257348/how-can-i-remove-a-class-from-an-element-with-jquery-based-on-some-characters-of/9257394#9257394)

These worked in fiddle but my application is just a bit different. I have the following:

```
<span id="refType_1" class="refType indent_02">Link Header</span>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
if (action == "Edit") {
   var parent = linkObj.closest("tr");
   parent.find(".refType").html($("#Type :selected").text());  // 1
   parent.find(".refType").className.replace(/indent_\d+($|\s)/, "xxx"); 
   parent.find(".refType").trim(this.className.replace(/(^|\s)indent_\d+($|\s)/, " "));
```

I tried the last two ways of replacing the class name with "" but both give me an error. For example the last method gives the following:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'trim'
```

I think I'm 99% towards getting it working but would appreciate advice. I tried a few different ways so far and it still does not work.

Please note the line with comment // 1 does work. I can change the contents of the span as needed. What does not work is:

```
parent.find(".refType").className.replace(/indent_\d+($|\s)/, "xxx");   or
parent.find(".refType").trim(this.className.replace(/(^|\s)indent_\d+($|\s)/, " "));
```

These are my two different attempts to get the text indent_xx to be removed from the span.

Comment: I think your going to need to add some more HTML ... how does this javascript get called ? from where ?

Comment: Could you please post all the HTML which is relevent. Your jQuery has references to elements which aren't shown.

Comment: You can't use `className` or `trim` on a jQuery object. use [0] to get the actual DOM object, or use `addClass` and `removeClass`

Comment: what are you trying to remove? is it just one span class or a number of span classes?

Comment: It is just the last two lines (same function) that I cannot get to work. I just added the first line marked // 1 to show that the parent.find is getting the span correctly and making changes.

Comment: @Jessica we need the full HTML to know what elements `parent()` and `this` refer to in your code.

Comment: Everything is noted in the last question together with some good answers. I am just trying to remove the part of the class name indent_xx where xx is any two numbers. It's all working in fiddle but the bit that's not working is when I try and do it to the parent.find element.  parent.find(".refType") works good and finds the span.

Comment: so basically you are trying to find all elements to see if there is a class that has indent_xx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not implement the code from the previous answer correctly.

You cannot do either of these because `.className` is a property of a DOM object, not of a jQuery object and you aren't even assigning the result of the `.replace()` to anything:

```
parent.find(".refType").className.replace(/indent_\d+($|\s)/, "xxx"); 
parent.find(".refType").trim(this.className.replace(/(^|\s)indent_\d+($|\s)/, " "));
```

If you following the design pattern from the previous answer, you would use this:

```
parent.find(".refType").each(function() {
    this.className = $.trim(this.className.replace(/(^|\s)indent_\d+($|\s)/, " ")); 
});
```

If you know there are no other classes on those objects that you want to keep except the .refType, you can do it even simpler:

```
parent.find(".refType").attr("class", "refType");
```

This just sets the entire class name to "refType", eliminating any other classes that might have been there.

You could also make a jQuery plug-in that you would put somewhere in your initialization code:

```
$.fn.removeIndentClasses = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        this.className = $.trim(this.className.replace(/(^|\s)indent_\d+($|\s)/, " ")); 
    });
    return this;
}
```

Then, your code would just be this:

```
parent.find(".refType").removeIndentClasses();
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have given the full details in the last question but I tried to trim down my question to just the thing I was a problem with. In my code I have "var parent = linkObj.closest("tr");
   parent.find  etc  and it works good. Now I tried to add your answer to that but have a problem. I am using this to remove the indent_xx from the element that has a class of refType on the row of my grid. There will only be one of these elements within parent.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I could simplify this. The thing is there will only ever be one instance of indent_xx in the class name. Can I do this without needing an each?

Comment: @Jessica - I added a simpler option if you know there are no other class names on the object that you want to keep besides "refType".  The way to do it without .each() would involve changing the code into a plug-in and the each would be done inside the plugin.

Comment: @Jessica - I added a jQuery plugin option that would do this.

Comment: thanks - your last answer parent.find(".refType").attr("class", "refType"); worked great.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you are trying to access properties that are not defined for jQuery objects. In the case of `className`, it is available to DOM elements, and in the case of `trim` it is available to strings (if the browser supports it).

I am assuming you want the code to apply to all `.refType` elements. If that's the case:

```
parent.find(".refType").each(function() {
    this.className = $.trim(this.className.replace(/(^|\s)indent_\d+($|\s)/, " "));
}).html($("#Type :selected").text());
```

This should replace the three lines beginning with `parent.find`. Inside an `each` loop, `this` refers to the DOM element rather than a jQuery object, so it will have a `className` property.

You need to actually set the value of the `className` (`this.className = newClassName`) rather than simply modifying it.

Also note that I have used jQuery's `$.trim` function because older browsers do not support the native `trim` function.

**Edit** (see comments)

I think from your comment what you mean is that there is only one `.refType` element and therefore you don't want to use an `each` loop. You can access the underlying DOM elements from a jQuery object using either the `get` method or array index:

```
parent.find(".refType")[0].className = newClassName;
```

Comment: I already use var parent = linkObj.closest("tr"); to get to a row in my grid. Each row has just the one single .refType element.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for trim is wrong - it's a function stored in the jQuery namespace, not a jQuery method. Also, replace isn't a mutating function (i.e. it creates a new string rather than changing the original one). And finally, className is a property defined on DOM nodes, but not on jQuery wrappers for DOM nodes, so you need to get the actual DOM node by getting the first one stored in the jQuery collection.

```
parent.find(".refType")[0].className = parent.find(".refType")[0].className.replace(/(^|\s)indent_\d+($|\s)/, " ");
```

will work without trimming (which almost certainly isn't necessary anyway as trailing whitespace in classnames doesn't normally have any impact on most apps). But if you really want to trim the whitespace use

```
var target = parent.find(".refType"),
    newClass = $.trim(target[0].className.replace(/(^|\s)indent_\d+($|\s)/, " "));
    target[0].className = newClass;
```